# Postgresql LIKE ANY versus LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've tried to be thorough in this question, so if you're impatient, just jump to the end to see what the actual question is...

I'm working on adjusting how some search features in one of our databases is implemented.  To this end, I'm adding some wildcard capabilities to our application's API that interfaces back to Postgresql.

The issue that I've found is that the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` times do not make sense to me and I'm trying to figure out where I could be going wrong; it doesn't seem likely that 15 queries is better than just one optimized query!

The table, `Words`, has two relevant columns for this question: `id` and `text`.  The `text` column has an index on it that was build with the `text_pattern_ops` option.  Here's what I'm seeing:

First, using a `LIKE ANY` with a `VALUES` clause, which [some references](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/) seem to indicate would be ideal in my case (finding multiple words):

```
events_prod=# explain analyze select distinct id from words where words.text LIKE ANY (values('test%'));
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=6716668.40..6727372.85 rows=1070445 width=4) (actual time=103088.381..103091.468 rows=256 loops=1)
   Group Key: words.id
   ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..6713992.29 rows=1070445 width=4) (actual time=0.670..103087.904 rows=256 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((words.text)::text ~~ "*VALUES*".column1)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 214089311
         ->  Seq Scan on words  (cost=0.00..3502655.91 rows=214089091 width=21) (actual time=0.017..25232.135 rows=214089567 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=214089567)
               ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.226 ms
 Execution time: 103106.296 ms
(10 rows)
```

As you can see, the execution time is horrendous.

A second attempt, using `LIKE ANY(ARRAY[...` yields:

```
events_prod=# explain analyze select distinct id from words where words.text LIKE ANY(ARRAY['test%']);
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=3770401.08..3770615.17 rows=21409 width=4) (actual time=37399.573..37399.704 rows=256 loops=1)
   Group Key: id
   ->  Seq Scan on words  (cost=0.00..3770347.56 rows=21409 width=4) (actual time=0.224..37399.054 rows=256 loops=1)
         Filter: ((text)::text ~~ ANY ('{test%}'::text[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 214093922
 Planning time: 0.611 ms
 Execution time: 37399.895 ms
(7 rows)
```

As you can see, performance is dramatically improved, but still far from ideal...  37 seconds. with one word in the list.  Moving that up to three words that returns a total of 256 rows changes the execution time to well over 100 seconds.

The last try, doing a LIKE for a single word:

```
events_prod=# explain analyze select distinct id from words where words.text LIKE 'test%';
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=60.14..274.23 rows=21409 width=4) (actual time=1.437..1.576 rows=256 loops=1)
   Group Key: id
   ->  Index Scan using words_special_idx on words  (cost=0.57..6.62 rows=21409 width=4) (actual time=0.048..1.258 rows=256 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((text)::text ~>=~ 'test'::text) AND ((text)::text ~<~ 'tesu'::text))
         Filter: ((text)::text ~~ 'test%'::text)
 Planning time: 0.826 ms
 Execution time: 1.858 ms
(7 rows)
```

As expected, this is the fastest, but the 1.85ms makes me wonder if there is something else I'm missing with the `VALUES` and `ARRAY` approach.

**The Question**

Is there some more efficient way to do something like this in Postgresql that I've missed in my research?

```
select distinct id
  from words
  where words.text LIKE ANY(ARRAY['word1%', 'another%', 'third%']);
```

Comment: Have you checked the regex or `similar to` version of that? Something like `words.text ~ '^(word1|another|third)'` or `words.text similar to '(word1|another|third)%`.

Comment: Yes.  The first version that you propose analyzes out at more than 202 seconds. All of my research says to avoid `SIMILAR TO` at all costs, and this is also borne out by analyze results of 197 seconds, just ahead of the regex.

Comment: Did you consider using a [full text index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)?

Comment: Well, since it's a table containing single terms in the "text" field, I'm not sure that's really the right approach here.  If this were a table with a field containing lots of text that would make more sense.

Comment: A full text index has different semantics, but a similar query against a million rows takes 13ms on my dev box.

Comment: The accepted solution below beats that at .393 ms against 100 million rows.

Comment: Will your queries always start with a constant string?

Comment: Yes.  Hence the left anchored examples. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit speculative.  I think the key is your pattern:

```
where words.text LIKE 'test%'
```

Note that the `like` pattern starts with a constant string.  The means that Postgres can do a range scan on the index for the words that start with `'test'`.

When you then introduce *multiple* comparisons, the optimizer gets confused and no longer considers multiple range scans.  Instead, it decides that it needs to process all the rows.

This may be a case where this re-write gives you the performance that you want:

```
select id
from words
where words.text LIKE 'word1%'
union
select id
from words
where words.text LIKE 'another%'
union 
select id
from words
where words.text LIKE 'third%';
```

Notes:

- The `distinct` is not needed because of the `union`.
- If the pattern starts with a wildcard, then a full scan is needed anyway.
- You might want to consider an n-gram or full-text index on the table.

Comment: That's very interesting... The union performs at 0.393 ms

Comment: I'm curious if there's a way to better instruct the optimizer without doing lots of unions...  Though this isn't a bad solution, it feels like it's the wrong way to approach the problem from a SQL point of view.

Comment: Maybe you can try `WHERE words.text LIKE 'word1%' OR words.text LIKE 'another%' OR ...`. That way you might end up with a bitmap index scan, which is slower than an index scan, but faster than a sequential scan.

Comment: I'm not sure that will improve over the union, which also eliminates the distinct.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer . . . Oh, for hints in Postgres.  But that's a religious argument, and we don't want to go there.

Comment: I love the line, "Failure to actually improve query performance: most of the time, the optimizer is actually right." on the postgresql page discussing hints... It is usually right.. except when it's not.  And hints aren't for queries against small datasets.. it's always the big ones where they are needed.  Anyway... Will accept this unless someone comes up with something better in the next day.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer . . . This sort of "skip-range-scan" is something that Postgres really should implement.  Oracle does have this functionality, and it is very useful in handling `or`-style conditions.